# Magento SOAP salesOrderInvoiceCreate not recognising order

Tags: php, magento, soap

I'm trying to raise order invoices via the Magento SOAP API , however I'm getting an 'Order Not Exists' error for an increment ID I know exists.

The XML being generated by my SOAP request is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >
        <soap:Body>
            <salesOrderInvoiceCreate xmlns="urn:Magento">
                <sessionId>a4b84a4900415cb6a61b3f81e4fxxxx4</sessionId> 
                <orderIncrementId>100000001</orderIncrementId>
                <itemsQty SOAP-ENC:arrayType="SOAP-ENC:Array[1]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
                    <item><order_item_id>1</order_item_id>
                    <qty>1.0000</qty>
                    </item>
                </itemsQty>
                <email>liam@xxxxxxx.com</email>
             </salesOrderInvoiceCreate>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And the response I'm getting back is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
<faultcode>103</faultcode>
<faultstring>Requested order not exists.</faultstring>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Not sure if I'm not passing through the correct value, but the other methods I'm using (loading orders etc) all work as expected.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so apparently the documentation is wrong.

According to the Magento docs:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrderInvoice/sales_order_invoice.create.html

It's expecting an argument of orderIncrementId

However, I've checked the WSDL, and it's expecting a field of invoiceIncrementId, although it should still contain the increment id of the order - go figure.